# Make a function to check if user exists

Tags: php, function

So i try to make a function for my register site to check if a username, email or ip exists. And like to check them seperat. So i can output to the user that what exists. But somehow this isn`t working.


So now its checked ok but doesn't pass for a other name.

This is the function.
function.php file

```
  function checkExists($con, $username, $email, $ip) {
    //check for existing stuff
    $userCheck = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? OR ip = ?";
    $check = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($check, $userCheck)) {
        $errors = "sql not working!";
    }
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($check, "ssi", $username, $email, $ip);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($check);
    
    $resultData= mysqli_stmt_get_result($check);
    
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
        $username = $row['username'];
        return $username;
        $email = $row['email'];
        return $email;
        $ip = $row['ip'];
        return $ip;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($check);
    
  }
```

register.php file
And here is the way i like to check it:

```
        elseif(checkExists($con, $username, $email, $ip) === $username) {
            $errors = "Username does already exists!";
        }
```

Comment: The function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything, so the `elseif` will always fail to `false`.

Comment: So i can return the $row right but how can i call it back in the elseif?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Barmar, the function returns nothing

Modify your function to return a meaningful value, updated your function, can try it

```
function checkExists($con, $username, $email, $ip) {
    //check for existing stuff
    $userCheck = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? OR ip = ?";
    $check = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($check, $userCheck)) {
        $errors = "sql not working!";
    }
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($check, "ssi", $username, $email, $ip);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($check);
    
    $resultData= mysqli_stmt_get_result($check);

    $checkedUser = "";
    $checkedEmail = "";
    $checkedIp = "";
    
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
        $checkedUser = $row['username'];
        $checkedEmail = $row['email'];
        $checkedIp = $row['ip'];
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($check);

    if($checkedUser == $username)
       return $username;
    else if($checkedEmail == $email)
       return $email;
    else if($checkedIp == $ip)
       return $ip;

    return "";
    
  }
```